# What are keys for in Diablo 2?

Tags: diablo-ii

I've just started Diablo 2 in single player mode, and there is one thing I don't understand.

Some opponents drop keys, generally in multiple numbers (like 6 of them stacked).  I can buy them in the towns, too.  They seem to be generic, and don't have to be identified, so no mystery there.

What do they open?

Can I sell them without worrying about that they might be useful later?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Keys are used to unlock locked chests, which are scattered across the game world. As per [this page](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Misc):

> Keys are dropped by monsters or purchased for a very low price in
>   town. They stack 12 high, and are readily available. Each time you
>   open a locked chest, one of your keys is used, and destroyed. There
>   are no locked doors, and never anything in a locked chest you have to
>   have to advance in the game. They are purely a bonus item, but as
>   locked chests are common, you should be sure to always carry some of
>   these (unless you play an Assassin, who can pick locks).

Comment: hm. so far I haven't encountered any locked chests or didn't realize to have opened them with a key, then :)

Comment: It's very easy when clicking away to not realize that you're unlocking them with a key, if you have keys in your inventory.  They make a slightly different sound when you unlock them, as compared to normal chests, I believe.  But since most of the time I'm just hastily clicking chests, I don't notice it most of the time either.  It's nice to have a few keys available at any given time, but you need not worry about having multiple stacks.

Comment: I actually remember how annoying it is when you **do not** have keys. Having your brawny barbarian say something like "I don't have any keys" is rather absurd when he is holding a giant axe that he uses to liberally dispose of similarly large monsters.

Comment: Still, I miss the days where a specific key and no other was necessary to open a specific chest, if it ever was able to be opened.

Comment: Also to notice, in the expansion, if you're playing as an Assassin, you don't need keys to open locked chests.

Answer (score -3):

It is about those three keys that you can only use them în hell mode on level 5 Harrogath http://www.d2tomb.com/hell_mystery.shtml

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding what keys are being referenced.